# Creating stack of stack in Java

Tags: java, stack

I want to create a stack of Integer stack. So that I can push a new integer stack in main stack.

How to create it?
I have done the following code for that:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Containers{
    static Stack<Integer> subStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    static Stack<subStack> main  = new Stack<subStack>();
   public static int addToStatck(char cont){
       //for(int j=0;j<)
        return 0;
    }
    public static void main(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String container = sc.next();
        Stack sub = new Stack();
        sub.push(container.charAt(0));
        main.push(sub);
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<container.length();++i){
            ans+=addToStatck(container.charAt(i));
        }

    }

}
```

it Shows me the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no `subStack` type (unless you create such type).

The type of `main` should be:

```
static Stack<Stack<Integer>> main = new Stack<>();
```

And there doesn't seem to be any use to your

```
static Stack<Integer> subStack = new Stack<Integer>();
```

variable.

Besides,

```
Stack sub = new Stack();
```

should be

```
Stack<Integer> sub = new Stack<>();
```

To summarize:

```
public class Containers{
    static Stack<Stack<Integer>> main = new Stack<>();
    public static int addToStatck(char cont){
        //for(int j=0;j<)
        return 0;
    }
    public static void main(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String container = sc.next();
        Stack<Integer> sub = new Stack<>();
        sub.push(Integer.valueOf (container.charAt(0)));
        main.push(sub);
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<container.length();++i){
            ans+=addToStatck(container.charAt(i));
        }   
    }  
}
```

Comment: import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Containers{
    static Stack<Stack<Character>> main  = new Stack();
   public static int addToStatck(char cont){
        return 0;
    }
    public static void main(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String container = sc.next();
        Stack<Character> sub = new Stack<Character>();
        sub.push(container.charAt(0));
        main.push(sub);
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<container.length();++i){
            ans+=addToStatck(container.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}

Comment: I have done the above code. But it still showing me the error: Container.java  contains unchecked or unsafe operation.

Comment: @Andy.inamdar Either change your inner Stack to a `Stack<Character>`, or change `sub.push(container.charAt(0));` to `sub.push(Integer.valueOf (container.charAt(0)));`

Comment: @Andy.inamdar you can't add a char to a Stack of Integer, since there's no automatic conversion from char to Integer.

Comment: I haven't created the stack of integer. I have created the of character.

Comment: @Andy.inamdar the code in that comment passes compilation.

Comment: In my cmd, it doesn't passes.

Comment: @Andy.inamdar Perhaps you are not compiling the code you think you are compiling. I tested your code in Eclipse.